# GWT: current URL of Frame(s)

Tags: events, gwt, frame

I have a GWT application that features two frames (com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame). Via Frame.setUrl(...) I can load arbitrary web pages without any problems. Of course, user then can click on links on the loaded pages, which in turn load the corresponding pages? How can I keep track of the currently loaded pages in both frames?

Below are my current attempt using two types of listeners; I found the code snippets on the Web. Both events fire, but still I don't know how to get the current loaded URL

```
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.LoadEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.LoadHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.EventListener;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Frame;

public class BrowserTabFrame extends Frame implements EventListener {

 public BrowserTabFrame() {
    super();
    sinkEvents(Event.ONLOAD);

    addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {      
        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getSource());
            // <iframe style="visibility: visible;" id="ext-gen17" src="http://..." class="gwt-Frame"></iframe>
            // however, the src attribute never changes
        }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
    super.onBrowserEvent(event);
    if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONLOAD) 
        System.out.println(event.getCurrentEventTarget());
        // [object HTMLIFrameElement]
        // no idea what to do with it   
  }
}
```

Thanks for any hints!

Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `src` attribute of an `iframe` will never change but the `URL` property of the contained `document` will. You can get this value using JSNI:

```
private native String getIframeUrl(IFrameElement frame) /*-{
  if (frame.contentDocument !== undefined) {
    return frame.contentDocument.URL;
  } else if (frame.contentWindow !== undefined &&
             frame.contentWindow.document !== undefined)
  {
    return frame.contentWindow.document;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}-*/;

...

Window.alert(getIframeUrl(myFrame.getElement()));
```

However note that, if the security context (any of protocol, domain or port number) of the `iframe` changes, the browser will not allow the containing application to access the `document` in the frame.

Comment: Hi, Jason! Thanks for your reply! This was exactly the information I was looking for. And as expected I run into this security issue. Is there any alternative / best-practice technique to realize some minimal web browser capability within a GWT application? If I could keep track of the links clicked within an IFrame that would be basically enough. Thanks, again! Christian

Comment: No, there is no way around this limitation using Javascript alone.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension of Jason's solution above. When I tried Jason's code it appeared that the returned URIs are missing hashes (aka fragments, URI suffixes beginning with '#'), and I needed these. After some digging around the DOM spec, the following worked:

```
public static native String getIframeUri(IFrameElement iframe) /*-{
    if (iframe.contentDocument !== undefined) {
        if (iframe.contentDocument.defaultView !== undefined
                && iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.location !== undefined) {
            return iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.location.href;
        } else {
            return iframe.contentDocument.URL;
        }
    } else if (iframe.contentWindow !== undefined
            && iframe.contentWindow.document !== undefined) {
        return iframe.contentWindow.document;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}-*/;
```

Where the only addition to Jason's code is the nested condition:

```
if (iframe.contentDocument.defaultView !== undefined
        && iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.location !== undefined) {
    return iframe.contentDocument.defaultView.location.href;
```